# What is the memory formula of Redis Sorted Set?

Tags: redis

I need to calculate how much memory a Redis SortedSet takes assuming my average element of the Sorted Set is X bytes.

Comment: I doubt there is any documentation on this, short of looking at the source itself. I would just try inserting a large realistic bulk of generated data and see.

Comment: See the code of https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/blob/master/rdbtools/memprofiler.py

Comment: Hi Ishay, did you try my solution? I hope it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the average size of an element *before* it's stored in redis, just do this:

- Clear redis of all data: command `flushall` (dumps all databases)
- Command `info`, check field `used_memory_human` (should be zero or close to it)
- Add/store data in redis
- `info` again, check `used_memory_human`, size indicates memory used by redis to store objects.

Hope it helps